# I want to apply Jeffrey divergence / Jensenshannon divergence for two histogram. Where data of histogram is not a probability distribution

Tags: dataset

I found Jeffrey formula as
[image]

here hi and ki are bin data of two histograms.

[https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~efros/courses/LBMV07/Papers/rubner-jcviu-00.pdf](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eefros/courses/LBMV07/Papers/rubner-jcviu-00.pdf)

I want to find Jeffrey divergence.

**There is any library implementation for this?**
I found an implementation on scipy but that is for probability distribution and I want for frequency histogram.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.jensenshannon.html